# The thing that I (take into account / consider ) the most when I buy shoes is if I can wear the shoes for a long time as it is strong

Tags: word-usage

I feel both of them are the same meaning, but I'd like to know if there's any difference.

> The thing that I (take into account / consider ) the most when I buy shoes is if I can wear the shoes for a long time as it is strong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use them both; they are [synonymous](http://www.thesaurus.com/browse/consider).

> **Synonyms for consider**
>
> - take into account

*Source: Thesaurus.com*